# Loop through objects containing array of objects in reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am new to reactjs.
I have a survey question answer UI, where I can enter question title and have the option to select the type of option.
If I select Text and Boolean type no option will be provided.
But if I select Lsit or Multiselect etc,  a text box will be provided to add options.
So when I select Text type

```
{...questions.map((x, idx) => ( console.log(questions[idx] )) )}
```

I get the output like this first time

```
Object {
"text": "asdsad",
"type": "text",
 "options": null
}
```

First time options will be null which is fine. So I just need the question title and type to DB.
Then on clicking on 'List' type in my UI , this console becomes :

```
Object{
 "text": "asdsad",
 "type": "list",
 "options": [
   {
    "value": "sdsad"
   }
```

]
}

I need to check whether options.value is set or not every time. If it is set then I need to look whether options.value is null or not for validation. How can I get that in the below loop.

```
{...questions.map((x, idx) => ( console.log(questions[idx] )) )}
```

Comment: `questions.filter(x => x.options !== null).map(...)`?

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of your code, here is a function that you can use to validate your questions. It will return a boolean true/false.

It uses [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to test that all questions match the condition. The condition that the options are not null.

```js
const isQuestionsValid = (questions) => {
  return questions.every((question) => question.options !== null);
};
```